# Oracle query to show change of status in each row with previous status

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a table with following rows

[image: see the image]

Need to write an oracle sql query to get the output as:

[image: see the result image here]

P.S: I am using Oracle 9i. Let me know if this can be done by just using oracle 9i sql.

Comment: Please learn to post data as text and analytic functions...

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sure, will definitely learn the analytic functions and also how to post as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select proj_name, prev_status || ' to ' || status
from (select t.*, lag(status) over (partition by proj_name order by date) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is not null;
```